# How to implement the audio input level functionality in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, navigator

As you can see in the below screenshot, here we have an input level detector which increases or decrease as per the selected audio devices volume.

I want to implement the same functionality in javascript. I have gone through the media method like **navigator.mediadevices.getusermedia** but still can't understand how can we implement the input level like below.

[image]

Comment: "Sliding-Windpw RMS calculation" should get you started.